# how to set icon and text inline on header of in phonegap app?

Tags: html, css, cordova

```
____________________________________________________________
| logo_icon              page_Tittle                       |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to make a header of my phonegap app like this one. On the left of the header there should be a logo(img) and on center there should be page tittle(text). Now I have already try this one.

```
<div data-role="header" >
            <div class="logo"  > <img src="img/logo.png"  /> </div>
            <h1 id="tittle">Main Page</h1>
            <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" class="ui-btn-right"  data-transition="fade" onclick="exitButtonClick()">Exit</a>          
        </div>
```

and the css its css is:

```
.logo {
    vertical-align: left;
}
.tittle{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Kindly help me how it will be work? I am new in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div data-role="header" class="header" >
        <div class="logo"  > <img src="img/logo.png"  /> </div>
        <h1 id="tittle">Main Page</h1>
        <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" class="ui-btn-right"    data-transition="fade" onclick="exitButtonClick()">Exit</a>          
    </div>
```

the css:

```
     .header{display:inline-block;
             padding:5px 15px;
             text-align:center;
             width:100%;
             }

     .logo{float:left;}

     .header h1 {font-size:15px;
                 width:80%;
                 text-align:center;}
```

basically, by adding the text align property of the header div as center, and setting the float property of the logo element to left, should solve your problem

check out the js fiddle link :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Hkj/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
.logo {
    float:left;
}
.tittle{
    text-align: center;
    width:75%; margin:0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do that with max number of `%` size and position in your css and use a `JavaScript` function for center the elements depending of the window size.
Anyway I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9947/) example for you, take a look and some ideas.

HTML:

```
    <div id="top_bar">
        <img id="logo_top_bar" src="../img/logo_top_bar.png">
        <section id="title">App title</section>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#top_bar{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height: 60px;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgb(46, 42, 42);
}

#logo_top_bar{
    position:absolute;
    height:30px;
    width:70px;
    left:4%;
    top:15px;        

}

#title{
    position:absolute;
    left:45%;
    top:16px;        
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color:white;

}
```